# Rails 4. Breakpoint gem path error. File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, breakpoint-sass

**Problem:**

I have a basic `Rails 4.0.10` project where I want to use `breakpoint` for media queries.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.10'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'httparty'

gem 'requirejs-rails'

gem "github_api"

gem "breakpoint", "~>2.4.0"

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

When I am requiring breakpoint in my sass stylesheets it throws:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Stats#index
Showing /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
Load paths:
  /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/app/assets/fonts
  /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/app/assets/images
  /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/requirejs-rails-0.9.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/breakpoint-2.4.6/lib/stylesheets
  (in /home/action/workspace/sofapp/sofa/app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss:5)
```

As you can see from error Sass cannot find right path to load breakpoint. I have looked to the last path and find out that directory `/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/breakpoint-2.4.6/lib/stylesheets` doesn't exist, instead we have `/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/breakpoint-2.4.6/stylesheets`.

**Question:**

Should I configure asset-pipeline to include the right path for breakpoint or there is some other issue?